# Writing TXT File with PHP, Want to Add an Actual Line Break

Tags: php, text-files, line-breaks

I am writing a TXT file using PHP. I want to insert actual line breaks into the TXT file wherever necessary. I have tried all combinations of \n \r \r\n \n\r ... but these are not causing any linebreaks to appear - in most cases, I am seeing the text "\n" appear in the TXT file, with no linebreak.

I have also tried chr(13).

Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: some source would be helpfull

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sounds to me like you might be using single quotes, i.e. `'\n'` rather than `"\n"`.

If you wanted to continue with a single quotes bias (as you should!), two options:

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt', 'Hello friend!
This will appear on a new line.
As will this');

// or

file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt', 'Hello friend!'."\n".'This will appear on a new line.'."\n".'As will this');
```

Answer (score 30):

For "\n" to work, you need to use double quotes, not '\n'.

**But** you should use the constant **PHP_EOL** instead, so that it adapts automatically to the OS ("\n", "\r" or "\r\n").

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', 'Bla' . PHP_EOL . 'Bla');
```

Comment: I could not find PHP_EOL on php.net, where can i learn more about what this does? Thanks!

Comment: Please note that PHP_EOL is the default line ending of the **server**. It's useful unless you're generating a file for download.

Answer (score 3):

\r\n in a windows server
\n in linux
Make sure you upload the file as ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

You must write `\n` in a **double-quoted** string (in single-quoted strings no parsing takes place):

```
"foo\r\nbar"
```

Further reference:

http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

you could also use `chr(10)` which is line break.