# Storing text in variable with line breaks

Tags: php

I'm using this code from Google NL processor API:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\NaturalLanguage\NaturalLanguageClient;

$projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';

$language = new NaturalLanguageClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId
]);

$text = 'Hello, world!'; //THIS LINE IS THE ISSUE
# Detects the sentiment of the text
$annotation = $language->analyzeSentiment($text);
$sentiment = $annotation->sentiment();
echo 'Text: ' . $text . '
Sentiment: ' . $sentiment['score'] . ', ' . $sentiment['magnitude'];
return $sentiment;
```

Everything works fine with whatever text I put in. However, the API is capable of analyzing each individual line of text separately (you can try it here: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/). If you put in two different lines, then you get sentiments for each.

I'd like to recreate this, but no matter how I try to include a line break (using all the methods here: [Writing TXT File with PHP, Want to Add an Actual Line Break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857038/writing-txt-file-with-php-want-to-add-an-actual-line-break)), it's all being analyzed as one big text block.

Google says that content is sent in the following format (if this helps):

```
{
 "document":{
  "type":"PLAIN_TEXT",
  "language": "EN",
  "content":"'Lawrence of Arabia' is a highly rated film biography about \
            British Lieutenant T. E. Lawrence. Peter O'Toole plays \
            Lawrence in the film."
  },
  "encodingType":"UTF8"
}
```

Comment: How are you adding new lines to your text? It would also be helpful to know what the API interprets as new line

Comment: @dan08 Yes, I tried simply having them on different lines, `\n` `'\r\'` and several others. I've looked all through the documentation, but can't find anything.